# Clone bootsrap-select using jquery cloneya plugin on Bootstrap framework

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select, jquery-cloneya

I'm using [jquery-coloneya](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya/) plugin to clone DOM elements on Bootsrap Framework. 
I have a problem cloning bootstrap-select elements using [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin. 
I'm using this code:

```
$('.linee-fattura').cloneya({
    cloneThis       : '.toclone',
    cloneButton     : '.clone',
    valueClone      : true,
    dataClone       : true,
    deepClone       : true,
}).on('clone_before_clone', function (event, toclone, newclone) {
   $('.linee-fattura select').selectpicker('destroy');
}).on('clone_after_append',function (event, toclone, newclone) {
    $('.linee-fattura select').selectpicker({});
});
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Cloning elements generated by a framework is always flaky. If you want to do this, I'd suggest cloning the underlying `select` then instantiate a new Bootstrap-select instance on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Actually that's what I'm trying to do, ```.on('clone_after_append',function (event, toclone, newclone)``` it's supposed to do that.

Comment: That's my point, cloning all the elements and events created dynamically by a plugin does not tend to be very reliable. You would be better off cloning ***just*** the original `select` element, then instantiating a *new* instance of the `selectpicker()` plugin on that.